# Gray text on website has color

Tags: html, css

I came across some nice CSS designs that I am trying to replicate on my own site. The problem is, the designs were presented as images...screenshots of the actual page. This means I've been trying to replicate the design in my own CSS.

Here is the problem: the text I am rendering is colored as grayscale (all rgb values are equal) in my CSS, but if I screenshot my page and zoom in, you can see **colored** pixels throughout the text. The original design does not have those...it is perfectly gray, and thus, looks much more smooth.

Here is the original at regular size (very smooth looking):
[image]

And here it is zoomed in (notice that all pixels are grayscale): [image]

Now, here is my attempt at regular size (notice how rough it looks): [image]

And zoomed in (see all the colored pixels):[image]

What on earth in happening here? How can I achieve the smooth look of the original design, without the colored pixels?

Comment: This is [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering). Nothing to worry about.

Comment: The "colored" pixels are the artifacts of subpixel font rendering.  As far as I can tell, there is little you can do about that.

Comment: @PeterO. Well, you can change the settings on your own computer. But if you want the users on your webpage to see exactly the same as what you see, yes, then you have a problem. You will need to resort to image replacement tricks.

Comment: This is strange. The original author was somehow able to overcome this "subpixel rendering" in their web pages. I am at a complete standstill with this one.

Comment: See ClearType: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType

Answer (score 3):

The original author might have been using a different system when they took the screen shot. Mac and Windows machines smooth fonts differently. There is a -webkit-font-smoothing  property, but I think this will only apply to Safari on Mac in the future.

I often experiment with text-shadow to achieve smoother looking fonts. Results vary depending on how much contrast there is with the text and background.

[How To Properly Smooth Font Using CSS3](http://www.icondeposit.com/blog%3ahow-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3)